# How do you add doi, e-print (e.g., arxiv), MathSciNet and zbMATH links in a BibTeX bibliography?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, amsmath, amsbook

I am a beginner with BibTeX and I use `amsplain` as bibliography style.

> How can I customize my bibliography style to append *doi*, e-print
>   (e.g., *arXiv*), *MathSciNet*, and *zbMATH* links (in this order)?

One example of what I mean can be found in the following paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.04655.pdf.

Answer (score 1):

here is the bibtex entry for one of the items in the bibliography of the
cited article, as delivered by mathscinet.  the tags for the various elements
are the "official" ones used with `amsplain`, but not all are recognized
(see below).  zbl is not included in the mathscinet database,
nor is arxiv, but `ZBL` and `ARXIV` would be appropriate tags.

`amsplain` does not recognize `doi`, `zbl` or `arxiv`, so those
elements would be ignored.  with the tool `custom-bib` you can modify an
existing `.bst` file to provide absent features.

```
@article {MR735367,
    AUTHOR = {Thomason, Andrew},
     TITLE = {An extremal function for contractions of graphs},
   JOURNAL = {Math. Proc. Cambridge Philos. Soc.},
  FJOURNAL = {Mathematical Proceedings of the Cambridge Philosophical
              Society},
    VOLUME = {95},
      YEAR = {1984},
    NUMBER = {2},
     PAGES = {261--265},
      ISSN = {0305-0041},
     CODEN = {MPCPCO},
   MRCLASS = {05C35},
  MRNUMBER = {735367},
MRREVIEWER = {H. Kramer},
       DOI = {10.1017/S0305004100061521},
       URL = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S0305004100061521},
}
```

Comment: And how do I use custom-bib?

Comment: for `custom-bib`, you should read the user manual.  it's included in tex live: `texdoc custom-bib'.